# Why is my PHP is not inserting data into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I have this form to input data into a MySQL database. It's not giving me any errors, but also not inserting data. I have looked around the web, with no avail. I'm not sure if it's my code or maybe I've misconfigured my database. Here's all the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Steam Traps Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table tr > td { text-align: right; }
    table tr > td + td { text-align: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="FormHandler.php" method="post" >
    <table border="0">
<tr>
<td align="center"><h1>Steam Trap Form Input</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <tr>
        <td>Date of Survey</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="dateSurvey">
        </td>
        <tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Plant Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="plantName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Plant Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="plantLoc"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Plant Contact Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="plantContact"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Direction</td>
      <td><select name="direction">
             <option value="N">N</option>
             <option value="NE">NE</option>
             <option value="NW">NW</option>
             <option value="S">S</option>
             <option value="SE">SE</option>
             <option value="SW">SW</option>
             <option value="E">E</option>
             <option value="W">W</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Location (detailed as possible)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="location" size="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Floor Level</td>
        <td><select name="flrLevel">
            <option value="grd">Ground</option>
<option value="1st">1st</option>
<option value="2nd">2nd</option>
<option value="3rd">3rd</option>
<option value="4th">4th</option>
<option value="5th">5th</option>
<option value="6th">6th</option>
<option value="7th">7th</option>
<option value="8th">8th</option>
<option value="9th">9th</option>
<option value="10th">10th</option>
<option value="11th">11th</option>
<option value="12th">12th</option>
<option value="13th">13th</option>
<option value="14th">14th</option>
<option value="15th">15th</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elevation (in ft)</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="elevation" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr
    <tr>
      <td>Tag Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tagNum" size="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MFG Model Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mmn" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="size" size="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="pressure" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Service</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="service" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trap Conditions</td>
      <td><select name="trapCond">
             <option value="OK">OK</option>
             <option value="BT">BT</option>
             <option value="RCL">RCL</option>
             <option value="CP">CP</option>
             <option value="VO">VO</option>
        </select>


      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
      name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php

$dateSurvey = $_POST["dateSurvey"];
$plantName = $_POST["plantName"];
$plantLoc = $_POST["plantLoc"];
$plantContact = $_POST["plantContact"];
$direction = $_POST["direction"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$flrLevel = $_POST["flrLevel"];
$elevation = $_POST["elevation"];
$tagNumb = $_POST["tagNum"];
$mmn = $_POST["mmn"];
$size = $_POST["size"];
$pressure = $_POST["pressure"];
$service = $_POST["service"];
$trapCond = $_POST["trapCond"];



$sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "******");
mysql_select_db("******", $sql_connection) or die( "Unable to select database");


$sql = "INSERT INTO steamtraps (
            dateSurvey,
            plantName,
            plantLoc,
            plantContact,
            direction,
            location,
            flrLevel,
            elevation,
            tagNum,
            mmn,
            size,
            pressure,
            service,
            trapCond,
            ContactDateCreated,
        )
        VALUES (
            '{$dateSurvey}',
            '{$plantName}',
            '{$plantLoc}',
            '{$plantContact}',
            '{$direction}',
            '{$location}',
            '{$flrLevel}',
            '{$elevation}',
            '{$tagNum}',
            '{$mmn}',
            '{$size}',
            '{$pressure}',
            '{$service}',
            '{$trapond}',
            NOW()
        )";
mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);

mysql_close($sql_connection);


?>
```

Comment: did you check your database connection?

Comment: i see an extra comma after the last column in the query

Comment: Have you verified the entire query? In other words, what do you see if you `print $sql;` just before `mysql_query`

Comment: @RonakPatel I have another file on my server that checks connectivity. But, the `mysql_select_db("******", $sql_connection) or die( "Unable to select database");` checks it, unless there is a better way.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Alex I see `INSERT INTO ******* ( dateSurvey, plantName, plantLoc, plantContact, direction, location, flrLevel, elevation, tagNum, mmn, size, pressure, service, trapCond, ContactDateCreated ) VALUES ( '2014-07-12', 'BS GAS CO', 'Hamilton, AL', 'Bobby Shirley', 'N', 'Inside', 'grd', '3', '', 'Alacor 132456', '1/2"', '150', 'TRACER', 'OK', NOW() )`

Comment: @bobbyshirley and what happens if you run that query on the mysql command line or in phpmyadmin?

Comment: tagNum is empty. Does your table allow null values in that field?

Comment: Try not to copy and paste everything please. Only relevant information please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `mysql_query` to show errors meaningfully:

```
mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection) or die(mysql_error() . "<br/>Query was: " . $sql);
```

If you have an error, it will stop execution and you will see both the error and the query that was attempted to be executed.

Comment: Thank @mazzucci! I just need to fully use error detection! You rock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of PHP you are running, but `mysql_query` and other related commands have been deprecated since PHP-5.5.0. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Try using the newer `mysqli_query` (you will need to update all of your sql commands like mysqli_connect and mysqli_close to match).
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php